# How can I get an alignment for two different tokenizations? (e.g. BERT vs spaCy)

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I have two tokenizations for a text "I'll go there" as follows:

```py
a == ["I", "'ll", "go", "there"]
b == ["I'll", "go", "there"]
```

How can I efficiently get the following alignment?

```py
a2b == [[0], [0], [1], [2]]
b2a == [[0, 1], [2], [3]]
```

In addition, if two tokenizations are normalized differently, is there efficient way to get the alignment? 
"two tokenizations are normalized differently" means, for example:

```py
a == ["à", "la", "gorge"]
b == ["a", "la", "gorge"] # dropped accent
```

I want the following alignment result:

```py
a2b == [[0], [1], [2]]
b2a == [[0], [1], [2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an algorithm based on [shortest edit script](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) for this question, and created
a python library "tokenizations" written in Rust. (Repository: https://github.com/tamuhey/tokenizations)